# Reference to HTML-element that invoked an action

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm invoking an Ember action via a link:

```
<a {{action "openApps"}}>Apps</a>
```

and handling it in the appropriate controller

```
actions: {
  openApps: function() {
    //...
  }
}
```

How do I get a reference to the `<a>` which invoked the action inside the controller-function.

Comment: There may be a better way, but you could define a `click` action in your view/component, which will be passed an event, then do `this.send('openApps', event.target)` from that click handler, then write `openApps: function(target)`.

Comment: This is not a component and I'm not using  Views anymore since they are going to be deprecated

Comment: I think you're going to need a component for this. (For a similar question now a bit out of date, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18833951/get-action-target-element-in-ember.) By the way, what are you planning on doing with the `<a>` element once you have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny. Someone answered the question yesterday with exactly what I wanted but he/she deleted the answer. Therefore here it is:

It is perfectly possible to get the target of an action by using `window.event.target`:

```
actions: {
  openNav: function() {
    Ember.$(window.event.target).slideToggle();
  }
}
```